# Makefile: Syntax error /bin/sh: -c: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a simple Makefile:

```
git_repo := some_git_repo

repo: 
    if [ -v $(git_repo) ]; then \
        echo "exists!" \
    else \
        echo "not exist!" \
    fi;

clean: repo
```

Running `make clean` gives me an error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [repo] Error 2
```

I'm not quite sure what's the cause for this error. I've double checked the syntax countless times, checked many different StackOverflow questions and even tried running the bash code under the `repo` rule separately and it works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The backslashes are NOT removed by `make`. You need semicolons after your `echo`s, or else use `.ONESHELL` and remove all the backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need semicolons. The "\" effect is to put everything on the same line.

```
repo: 
    if [ -v $(git_repo) ]; then \
        echo "exists!"; \
    else \
        echo "not exist!"; \
    fi;
```

See the `echo` ends with a semicolon now.

Comment: ...and here I was thinking that I know enough CS to not make the semicolon mistakes anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The backslashes cause all the shell lines to be concatenated into one long line, which means you need semi-colons at the end of each line to separate the statements.

```
if [ -v $(git_repo) ]; then \
    echo "exists!"; \
else \
    echo "not exist!"; \
fi
```

After the backslashes and newlines are removed (and `$(git_repo)` is substituted) the shell sees:

```
if [ -v some_git_repo ]; then echo "exists!"; else echo "not exist!"; fi
```